# Doctrine 2, Mongo DB, Query Builder - how to define multiple equals values for a single field?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Referring to the docs:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#getting-single-result

I'd like to specify multiple values for a single field but can't figure out how to do this?

Here is an example from the docs:

```
<?php

$user = $dm->createQueryBuilder('User')
    ->field('username')->equals('jwage')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();
```

I'd like to get the documents where 'username' not only matches 'jwage' but also matches another username e.g. 'tthumb'.  Passing an array or comma separated string into equals seems intuitive as you can with select() but neither seem to work.  Maybe I am overlooking some field?

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use another method for that:

```
$user = $dm->createQueryBuilder('User')
           ->field('username')->in(array('jwage', 'tthumb'))
           ->getQuery()
           ->getSingleResult();
```

But as it is a query expecting **single** result you have to be sure that this query will return only one result. In other case it will throw you an error.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, makes complete sense.  Thanks this was spot on.  To get back multiple results I am using execute() instead of getSingleResult() in the example from their docs.  Thanks again! :)